# Hide UI element of a webpage from other page [wordpress]

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe, web

i'm new to web and facing issue while hiding a UI element in a webpage from another webpage. 
Scenario:

1. I've a WordPress site (Theme-TwentySeventeen).
2. I've added a **Logout** button programmatically on page as shown in image.
3. I've multiple posts,
   and every post has a button (**play video**).
4. When user taps on Play Video button, an **iframe** appears (fancybox). It has another button "**Login**".
5. I want to **show/hide** Logout button on main page *based on the click on "Login"* button in iFrame.

I tried to access Logout button using it's ID from iFrame. But it's not part of iFrame source code. and i was not able to access it.

P.S. I can show/hide logout button from the main page using JQuery.

**Query:**
Is there any way in web to pass notification from one page to other pages? Please guide

[image: Landing page]

[image: IFrame page]

Comment: Using an iFrame doesn't sound like the best design decision.  A modal window, eg jQueryUI's .modal, will avoid the need for separate pages.

Comment: I'm using Fancybox for this. I'm not sure what you're talking about because of zero experience in this domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this issue by accessing element from parent window. My code is as:

```
function showLogoutButton(){
    var logoutButton = window.parent.document.getElementById('logout');
    if (logoutButton) {
        logoutButton.style.display = 'block'
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a good practice. Please suggest if you've any other approach.